# Change default Python / Flask Console in PyCharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I could not find an answer for this:

I have a Flask project that has (by default) two consoles preset: One (ordinary) "Python Console" and one "Flask console":

[image: Pycharm Console Settings]

Now if I start a new console with the "+" symbol in the Console menu, it opens a "Flask Console" by default:

[image: Open new Console behaviour]

However I want the "Python Console" by default. In another PyCharm Flask project that I started a year ago, the "Python Console" starts by default, even though it appears to me that I have the same settings in both projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an answer in the official intellij-support forum ([see here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010471360-Pycharm-Change-default-Python-Flask-Console)). In Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flask: If you check the "Flask integration" option, the Console default will switch automatically to Flask Console:

[image]

It is not possible to manually switch the Console default independent of this option but it was suggested to do a feature request for that

Comment: Even if I disable Flask integration and without Flask installed in my environments I cannot switch back to the default Python console. What I found useful was to remove the code snippets importing flask.

Answer (score 0):

Go into .idea/workspace.xml and remove the Flask component. It's the only way I was able to remove it.